# How to create a blog archive system (grouping multiple similar year/month together)

Tags: php, sql

I have been meaning to create a blog archive system with only a little clue. This is where I am stuck

```
$ar = array('2012-3-02 23:14:29','2013-1-02 23:14:29',
'2014-2-02 23:14:29','2013-5-02 23:14:29');
for ($i =0; $i < count($ar); $i++){
$nw = explode(" ", $ar[$i]);
$nw2 = explode("-" , $ar[$i]);
echo "<br>";
echo $nw2[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $nw2[1];
}}
```

I have been thinking to group all similar years together and similar months under the same year together but I have no idea how to continue. Please advise thanks.

(this is a testing phase, the dateTime will be pulled from a database)

Comment: why aren't you grouping dates in the database? I don't follow what you are asking here.

Comment: Firstly i apologize for this unstructured question , if i'm not mistaken using group i can only get 1 result even i have 5result belong to the same group. What i want to achieve is to come out with 5result under the 1 group, say year2012. Once again sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You would order them in the mysql query, an example would be,

```
$dateFrom = '2012-01-01 00:00:00';
$dateTo = null;
if (is_null($dateTo)) $dateTo = 'NOW()';
$q = mysql_query("SELECT blogPosts FROM blogTable WHERE dateTime > $dateFrom AND dateTime < $dateTo ORDER BY dateTime DESC");
```

You could then have two input fields or select boxes with dates two and from, this could enable the user to select a start date and an end date for posts between that time.

The above code is just a very simple example of how it could be done.